# How to become a power user of gnome-do?

Tags: gnome-do, productivity

Just a few months back, I discovered `gnome-do`. I have heard that its a great tool for ubuntu. However, I haven't been able to use it except for starting/running applications like firefox, thunderbird, gedit etc.

It would be great if people can list all the great things that I can do with this nice tool.

Comment: This is relevant to my interests.

Comment: Reviewing the [available plugins](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Category:Plugins) would be a good start.

Comment: @ændrük, I have reviewed and installed all sorts of plugins, but still I am not able to use them efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review [these instructions](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Using_Do) from GNOME Do's website on what you can do with it.